# Android - I am having problems with adding more than 8 imageviews to RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, imageview, out-of-memory

[enter ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT3ld.jpg)

I need to add 24 images to RelativeLayout and I first tried it with XML,
which just shut down the app after I added 8th ImageView.
So I tried with coding like above, and it shows me that message.
It says OutOfMemory, failed to allocate ___ to a memory with 6mb OOM and I don't really know what it means but I am guessing image files are too large?
It caused error like that when I just tried with XML too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epjeY.jpg)

but the entire set of images are less than 100kb though.

How can I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have drawables in drawable folder. So if you have really large-density screen, it scales. You should create scaled images for all dpi's or init images manually:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.inScaled = false; 
bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                       R.drawable.imageName, options);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
```

or

```
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(imageId);
Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);  
imageview.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is OutOfMemory a common issue? Other solutions suggested adding LargeHeap=true in manifest file. Is that commonly done as well?

Comment: OutOfMemory can appear randomly, e.g. when Garbage Collector detected memory is full of garbage, but bitmaps are loading too quick. In case of repeating this error, try to resize bitmap and recycle old.
And also if the post really helped, i'd appreciate if you approve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Picssso library (http://square.github.io/picasso/). It has fit() method that is very useful for loading many images. Example:

```
Picssso.with(context).load(R.drawable.yourimage).fit().into(yourImageView);
```

Comment: thank you. Does this not require internet access if I use with R.drawable in load()?

Comment: No, it doesn't if image is on device (in your app drawable folder). It requires internet if you load image from url.